# How do I identify and locate large values in arrays?

Tags: c

```
array[10]={2,3424,4234,42,234,234,23423,123,342,3}
```

In this array, how do I find the first **five biggest numbers** and the position of those numbers? I.e I want the output as

> biggest number was 23423 and its position was 7

Like this ^^^ for the five biggest numbers and their positions.

I want code for this; I am a student.

Comment: The fact that you're student does not mean that you should just demand the code without trying to do an assignment yourself...

Comment: show us what you've come up so far.

Comment: Voting to close from a sense of disappointment in the youth of today -- you're a student you tell us, so study.

Comment: Vladimir@ i amble to print the biggest numbers not able to print the location

Comment: Can you show us anything you have tried so far? Homework is meant to be done by yourself. How do you want to learn anything if somebody else solves homework for you? First try to solve it yourself and then if you have any specific problem come back for a help.

Comment: The question has disappeared! I would fix it, but I don't have editing privileges.

Comment: @Mitch Flag for mod attention next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the array guaranteed to have 10 elements? Are they guaranteed to be positive? If so, you can multiply each element by 10 and add the index to it, then sort the array, then take the 5 largest elements; divide by 10 (integer division) to get the original number, and take % 10 to get the original position.

For a more general solution, you could create a struct to hold the value and original index, then sort the array of structs based on value.

Use any basic sorting algorithm.

Comment: Or the standard library `qsort` function!

Answer (score 0):

You just extend search algorithm for the largest number to search for n = 5 largest numbers.
If you use binary search, what should be done first with an array?  Well, if you answer this question, you'll probably won't need to binary search it at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the array should be immutable since you want to find the positions as well. So if I am correct you shouldn't sort the array, unless you use a new array of size 10, store the sorted array there, and compare and find between the two arrays etc.

If you want to find it without sorting you could do that :

Find the First biggest number and its position
Find the Second biggest number (which is smaller from the First biggest number) and its position
Find the third biggest number (which is smaller than the Second biggest number) ...

etc....

This can be done and it's not that hard.